# Problem using the align tool

Tags: adobe-illustrator, alignment

New to Illustrator. First time using the align tool. I'm trying to align an accent to a letter within a word.

I'm trying to vertical align it to the letter, but I'm doing something wrong. I've tried selecting the object and the letter then hitting vertical align but it just moves the entire word and not the object. What am I not doing correctly?

Answer (score 2):

It seems what you want to do is "Align to Key Object"

You would have to ungroup the letters and then select just the letter and the item you want to align with it.

---

- Convert your word to outlines: *Right Click > Convert to Outlines*

  - By default it is grouped, so make sure to Ungroup.

---

- Select objects (that you want to align) in your case, the *Letter* and the *Accent*
- Open the align panel: **Windows > Align** (or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>)

  - Select `Align to Key Object` and select the Letter as your Key Object (Your **Key Object** will be highlighted **bold**)
  - Then Align (based on where you need it)

[image: showing the align panel and bold key obj]

---

**Note**: If this is a font (and not a custom made letter or accent), some fonts will already contain the accents in their letters.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what I did, but somehow I was able to isolate the letter from the word and align the object to the letter. Started over and I went back and rechecked my create outlines from the menu, then my ungroup.