# When clicking on one of the active (selected) objects in Illustrator, its bounding box gets bolder. Why?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, selections

Why is it that when you click on one of the selected objects in Illustrator while using the Selection Tool, it has a bolder bounding box? What is this behavior called?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is the *key* object selection, which is used for alignment purposes (align to key object)

---

Some helpful links:

https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/100567/63979

https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/91059/63979

and

https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/moving-aligning-distributing-objects.html#main-pars_heading_13